# Proving that if $p$ is a prime number then $gcd (p, (p-1)!) =1$

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing, divisibility

I am just making sure whether this is a valid proof:

> Since $p$ is a prime number, then $p$ is only divisible by $1$ or $p$
>
> Suppose we want to take the $gcd (p,a)$ with a, an arbitrary integer. This would result in either $p$ or $1.$
>
> Similarly, the $gcd (p, (p-1)!)$ would be either $p$ or $1$. Note that $(p-1)! = (p-1) (p-2) ... (2)(1)$
>
> But the $gcd (p, (p-1)!)$ would not be $p$, since we cannot create p by multiplying the elements in $(p-1)$
>
> Hence the $gcd(p, (p-1)!) = 1$ and our proof is complete.

I am wondering whether is kind of proof is valid? Any other suggestions, or way of doing this proof, so that it looks more formal or legible? Thanks!

Comment: "... would not be $p$, since we cannot create $p$..." That needs to be clarified. The word "create" there is vague. Why can't that happen? It is true that it can't happen, buy you haven't explained why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to "Euclid's Lemma," which says that if the prime $p$ divides $ab$ then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$.

That can be readily extended (by induction, if you really want to do all the details) that if $p$ divides $a_1a_2\cdots a_m$, then $p$ divides at least one of the $a_i$.

So if $p$ divides $(p-1)!$, then $p$ divides at least one of $1,2,\dots,p-1$. This is easily seen to be impossible, since $p$ is greater than each of these.

**Another way:** By [Wilson's Theorem,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) $(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: oh yeah! I got what you mean there. From there can i just say like: Since the factor of $p$ is $p$ and itself, and because $p$ does not divide $(p-1)!$, then the $gcd (p, (p-1)!) = 1$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. The two arguments I gave were in order  to be more formal about the only weakness of your argument, the "obvious" assertion that $p$ cannot divide $(p-1)!$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. The only comment is that you might want to expand a bit where you say "we cannot create $p$ by multiplying the elements in $(p-1)$". Firstly, the way it is stated it is too vague. What you mean is "we cannot obtain $p$ as a product of two integers $1 < k,m < p$" but do you really understand yourself why this suffices to show that $p$ does not divide $(p-1)!$ (hint: this has a to do with $p$ being prime).

Comment: if I add it like this: since the factor of $p$ is just $1$ and itself. Would that suffice?

Comment: No, you need more than that, @Ingrida.